# Why can't I shrink volume on my local disk?

Tags: kubuntu

I want to shrink volume on my local disk and its saying I only have 10GB to shrink even though I have 120GB available. I have tried to turn off the powercfg /h off and the advanced system settings. also went on event viewer to see The last unmovable file.

Comment: You can mess with the partitions of a disk only if none of the disk's partitions is mounted. Boot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, or use any Live USB Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)